# trouble with extracting form data from another php page

Tags: php, forms

I want to create a checkbox and check whether checkbox is checked or not in another PHP page so I created form like :

```
 <form action="heartbeat.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="keepme">
    <input type="submit" value="log in">
    </form>
```

and then I tried to extract this input on heartbeat.php like:

```
 <?php
    /*
    * A PHP file for laying down a heartbeat JavaScript call.
    */
    if(!isset($_POST["keepme"])){
    $auto_logout = 10;
    }
    else{
    $auto_logout = 1000;
    }
    ?>
```

but it never gets `$_POST["keepme"]` value. Any idea??

Comment: easy hint, just print out the values you have in $_POST with print_r and then you'll know exactly what is sent.

Comment: I did that. it print nothing. it means that it did not get $_POST["keepme"]

Comment: Submitting button? And both files in same directory?

Comment: I do not have value but I will try now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't pass value to checkbox tag, the POST array will be empty. You need to do something like that

```
<input type="checkbox" name="keepme" value='1'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you have submit button

```
If(isset($_POST['submit-btn'])){
    echo  $_POST['keepme'];
}
```